# How to set Custom Platform Container Configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

While creating a custom platform for elastic beanstalk (following this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html), I ran into a bit of a snag.

The command

```
$ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
```

returns **/tmp**. I would like to change that, but could not find any info on how to do that.

This configuration comes from file **/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/configuration/containerconfiguration** which gets auto generated by CloudFormation, which I couldn't figure how to customize in the platform build.

One way to affect this property (that I found) is by adding .ebextension config file to application source directory that is deployed on the platform:

```
# .ebextension/container.config 
Resources:
    AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
        Metadata:
            AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Ext:
                _ContainerConfigFileContent:
                    container:
                        app_staging_dir: /var/app/ondeck
```

But I don't want to have to add such config file to each of the applications I deploy using this platform, if I can somehow achieve this through platform scripts.

If anyone knows how to affect the app_staging_dir container configuration, please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't been able to figure this out. Seeing that there has been no activity here either, I'm assuming it is currently impossible.

Eventually gave up the idea of custom platform and switch to docker platform, as it is much easier to maintain.